# What's the effect of normalizing for SVD?

Tags: svd

$\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $M$ is the number of data, $N$ is the dimension of data. Then one can have SVD as
$\mathbf{X= U\Sigma V^\top} $.

However, now I do the SVD on the *tranlsated* and *scaled* $\mathbf{X}$,
$$
Y = (\mathbf{X} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{\mu}
 ) \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}
$$
where $\mu$ is the mean of the data. $\Lambda$ is the standard deviation of the data for each dimension.

My question is, what is the relationship between the following SVD On $Y$ and $X$?
$$
Y = U_Y \Sigma_Y V_Y^\top
$$

For my own interests, is there any closed form relationship between $V_Y$ and $\mathbf{V}$?